# How to get Cabal Sandbox to install correctly linked HTML documentation?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock

I created a cabal library inside a sandbox with the following commands:

```
cabal sandbox init
cabal init
```

I added the line `documentation: True` to `cabal.config` to make sure that documentation is generated, and I added a dependency to the `vector` package in `mylib.cabal`. Then I ran:

```
cabal install --only-dependencies
```

I got the following output:

```
/scm/hs-proj/.cabal-sandbox
Configuring primitive-0.6...
Building primitive-0.6...
Installed primitive-0.6
Configuring vector-0.10.12.3...
Building vector-0.10.12.3...
Installed vector-0.10.12.3
Updating documentation index
/scm/hs-proj/.cabal-sandbox/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.1/index.html
```

So far so good.

When I opened the index file it contained links to a lot of packages, like:

```
file:///scm/hs-proj/.cabal-sandbox/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.1/Data-List.html
file:///scm/hs-proj/.cabal-sandbox/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.1/Data-Vector.html
```

But of these links pointed to any real files. Note that this is the case for the extra dependencies like `vector` and also for built-in packages list `Data.List`.

So I think I've installed the documentation incorrectly. Can someone point out how I've installed the documentation incorrectly and how to do it correctly?

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I think if you change the flag in your `~/.cabal/config` file for Documentation to True and uncomment it, clean the sandbox and reinstall it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your fault, this is a [known bug](https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/385) in haddock.
It only affects ghc 7.10, so a workaround could be to use ghc 7.8.4 until this is fixed.